# How to get Office365 mailbox usage data

Tags: api, office365

Is there some way to get the data that shows up in the office 365 portal for a user, specifically the last logon and the mailbox quota.  This is in a c# application using the office 365 apis version 0.1.1-alpha.  I am trying to query the information either with the APIs or if need be via REST call but am not able to find anything that comes close.  The code I have is based on O365APIsWin8Sample.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, mailbox statistics aren't exposed via their API.

You can read more about Office 365's exposed resourcse [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn605901(v=office.15).aspx#sectionSection1).